# devise - show required fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

is there a way to get devise to show * for required fields on sign up page in views? 
rails 3.0.5 devise 1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you run `rails generate devise:views` devise will generate its views into `app/views/devise`. Then you can add as many * as you like in there.

Have a look at the [simple_form gem](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form). It will add the * automatically and even provide inline validation. But this is just an addition, editing the views will solve your problem.

Comment: i see there's a class field_with-errors that is used when theres an error, it spans the whole row so if i need to display my * next to the field, it moves it to the next line instead. how can i override that style? where can i find it? devise hasn't added it to my stylesheet...

Comment: You do not need to override anything as you most probably have not defined anything. Just add the `field_with_errors` class to your own CSS and style it however you like…